# My app crashes down when a button is clicked

Tags: android

Whenever I click on the button(created by me), the emulator abruptly closes. Also, the button doesn't look like one on the emulator.
Following is the screenshot. 
Please help!

[image]

The code is below:

```
package com.example.demoap;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void clickFunction(View view) 
    {
        Log.i("Info", "Congratulations, button pressed!");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Comment: Switch to the logcat window and find the exception logs, then you'll find which lines of code caused the crash

Answer (score 4):

Please kill and start adb server from console or terminal using following commands:

```
adb kill-server 
adb start-server
```

If it does not help try to restart your computer.

If you are getting

> adb command not found

error then you have to go in platform-tools directory in Android SDK.

Also make sure you've added the 'clickFunction' in the 'OnClick' for the button.